# How to show downloading progress with URLSeassion

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm new to swift, I'm working on a project where it downloads content and save it to the camera roll with this code

```
    func downloadVideoLinkAndCreateAsset(_ videoURL: String) {
    // use guard to make sure you have a valid url
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: firstId) else { return }
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    // check if the file already exist at the destination folder if you don't want to download it twice
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(videoURL.lastPathComponent).path) {
        // set up your download task
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: videoURL) { (location, response, error) -> Void in
            // use guard to unwrap your optional url
            guard let location = location else { return }
            // create a deatination url with the server response suggested file name
            let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? videoURL.lastPathComponent)

            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location)
                let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL)
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
                let filePath="\(documentsPath)/template.mp4"
                urlData?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                }) { completed, error in
                                if completed {
                                    print("Video asset created")

                                } else {
                                    print(error)
                        }
                    }
            } catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription)}

            }.resume()
    } else {
        print("File already exists at destination url")
    }

}
```

I currently have a label to show the percentage of the downloaded bytes and a progress view to show the progress. 
I have searched for an answer and most of the answers I found were in objective-C, can you please help?

And can you please explain the diffrence between using URLSession and this to download content and if it's possible to implement the label and the progress view.

```
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                if let url = URL(string: videoLink),
                    let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url)
                {
                    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
                    let filePath="\(documentsPath)/template.mp4"
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
                        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                        }) { completed, error in
                            if completed {
                                print("Video is saved!")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The block- / closure-based API does not provide progress information.

You need to use the protocol / delegate-based API, adopt the [NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondownloaddelegate) protocol and and implement the method [urlSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate/1409408-urlsession)

```
optional func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                      downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
         didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, 
                 totalBytesWritten: Int64, 
         totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm getting this error `Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'URLSessionDownloadDelegate'`

Comment: Xcode solution was to add this function also `@available(iOS 7.0, *)
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        
    }`

Comment: Yes, of course, you have to implement also the required delegate methods to receive the data which correspond to `downloadTask(with`